# Can't connect to network

Tags: networking, 20.04

Fresh install of 20.04

It's a wired connection. It was working after restart for a few minutes, but after it dropped, and now I can't connect.

I have another PC connected to the same router, and it's working fine.

I was told Ubuntu and Linux would be easy, and work out of the box :/

Comment: I've had a long standing problem with 20.04 dropping internet connection without apparent cause and I've never been able to resolve it fully. what I do in terminal is `sudo service network-manager restart` and that seems to work fine... perhaps try that next time it drops out?

Comment: Unable to duplicate the problem. I've had fresh installs since 8.04 using wired networking and default networking settings, and they have worked flawlessly. It is indeed easy and does indeed work out of the box. First stop: Switch out the network cable (50% of my mysterious network failures are hardware, mostly cables gone bad). Second stop: Review your logs.

Comment: @user535733 interestingly, that's what I initially thought as was using a new Cat 6 cable and thought that might be suspect, but changed it out to a Cat 5E cable not having the same issue on a different PC but it persists on 20.04.04 LTS  Possibly not related though....

Comment: Look at the network logs with the terminal command: `sudo journalctl -b 0 -u NetworkManager`. Read `man journalctl`.